# Percentage to number in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2010

In Excel, I have a large column with percentage values, something like this :

```
N%
N%
N%
..
..
```

I don't want them to appear as percentages. I want to convert each percentage to the corresponding double value and eliminate '%' at the end. How can I do that in excel? Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to do it in VBA? You can do that via Excel menus as well?

Comment: You can use multiply all the values by 100, then reformat as numbers rather than percentages. One quick way here http://j-walk.com/ss/excel/usertips/tip059.htm. This is really a formula question for Super User

Comment: Selecting them all and changing the format to number isn't enough?

Comment: I want any fast way. Not necessarily VB. But I don't know how to use any of the functions in excel. I need steps.

Comment: Well look at my link above.

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/basic-tasks-in-excel-2010-HA101829993.aspx#_Toc256078350

Comment: @mattboy...Thanks it worked, but that didn't eliminate "%".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the column, right click, select Format Cells, go to the Number tab, select Number under category and select the number of decimals you want to appear in the Decimal places field.

Comment: Are you sure you understand what I want? I don't want to change the number of decimal places. I want to convert the percentage to a number. Meaning I want to divide the number in the percentage over 100

Comment: If this isn't what you want, then no.

Comment: Have you tried doing this?

Comment: If I didn't try it, I wouldn't have rated you up ;)
That's perfect. Thanks.

Comment: (what a weird set of comments)